# Import module with folder and passing data to module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I Found The Tutorial about 
[Designing a clean REST API with Node.js (Express + Mongo)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fy6-LSE_zjI)

project in [github](https://github.com/arcdev1/mm_express_api_example).

but the problem is i didn't get the concept of routing in one part.

> the misundrestanding part is how is it possible to pass `httpRequest` data to `handle` method within `contact-endpoint` module?
>   because `handle` method is in here 
> `export default function makeContactsEndpointHandler({ contactList }) {
>     return async function handle(httpRequest) {`

this is the `index` of project:

```
import handleContactsRequest from "./contacts";
import adaptRequest from "./helpers/adapt-request";

app.all("/contacts", contactsController);
app.get("/contacts/:id", contactsController);

function contactsController(req, res) {
   const httpRequest = adaptRequest(req);
   handleContactsRequest(httpRequest)
       .then(({ headers, statusCode, data }) =>
            res.set(headers).status(statusCode).send(data)
       )
       .catch((e) => res.status(500).end());
}
```

this is the `adaptRequest`:

```
export default function adaptRequest (req = {}) {
   return Object.freeze({
       path: req.path,
       method: req.method,
       pathParams: req.params,
       queryParams: req.query,
       body: req.body
  })
}
```

this is the `handleContactsRequest` module:

```
import makeDb from "../db";
import makeContactList from "./contact-list";
import makeContactsEndpointHandler from "./contacts-endpoint";

const database = makeDb();
const contactList = makeContactList({ database });
const contactsEndpointHandler = makeContactsEndpointHandler({ contactList });

export default contactsEndpointHandler;
```

this is part of `contact-endpoint` module:

```
export default function makeContactsEndpointHandler({ contactList }) {
    return async function handle(httpRequest) {
         switch (httpRequest.method) {
              case "POST":
                  return postContact(httpRequest);
              case "GET":
                  return getContacts(httpRequest);
         default:
             return makeHttpError({
                   statusCode: 405,
                   errorMessage: `${httpRequest.method} method not allowed.`,
             });
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`makeContactsEndpointHandler` is a function that returns a function (`async handle(xxx)`).

In `handleContactsRequest`, we export the result of the call: `makeContactsEndpointHandler({ contactList })`. Which is therefore the function `async handle(xxx)` itself.

So, in `index`, when we call `handleContactsRequest` with the constant `httpRequest` as argument, we're actually calling that `handle(xxx)` function. (I wrote `xxx` as parameter name to highlight the difference between the two `httpRequest` declarations.)

Comment: comprehended but there is something i forget to include in `index` import the folder that contains index file that is `handleContactsRequest ` how module loaded and get `httpRequest` parameter?

Comment: i read loading module from folder in nodejs but how `handleContactsRequest ` pass data to `makeContactsEndpointHandler` ?

Comment: i `console.log(httpRequest)` in `handleContactsRequest ` but get error undefined ...

Comment: ##  updated question in first code snippet, added the import ##